"Exact" definition of $\lambda$-displacement convexity
I am trying to understand the concept of $\lambda$-displacement convexity in optimal transport. However, I met different definitions of it and felt a bit confused.
Generally, geodesic is not necessarily a minimal geodesic in metric space as discuss here Why may geodesic not be the shortest path on a surface?. My main confusion is mostly related to this.

In Definition 16.5 of Villani's book, the definition of displacement is as following:

(https://i.sstatic.net/BvV5x.png
)
However, do we need the inequality to hold for every single geodesic instead of only hold for minimal geodesic? I'm not sure why the author would put brackets for "constant-speed, minimizing". Or, does it mean the definition is equivalent no matter with or without the restriction of "constant-speed, minimizing" geodesic?

In Definition 4.3.1 of Figalli's book "An Invitation to Optimal Transport, Wasserstein Distances, and Gradient Flows", he defines the displacement convexity as following:

(https://i.sstatic.net/CZVwe.png)
Here, the $W_2$-geodesic only refers to minimal geodesic.
Tips: There is a weaker version of displacement convextiy, which only requires the existance of convexity along one minimal geodesic. In some cases, this definiciton is equivalent to the second definition. But currently, it is not my main concern.
Sorry for the picture issue since I'm a freshman in Math StackExchange and thanks for the help in advance.
